# CSS - Flex property issue

Tags: css, flexbox

```
.class {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Hey guys I'm using this style to make div center. I gave this style to outer div so the inner content made it's self center. It's not working in internet explorer. Can we do something to make it working in explorer?

Comment: You can add the `-ms` prefix but you need to know that the flex works with IE 10+.

Comment: @Llazar Older IE versions of flex follow the old draft, not the current standard. The -webkit prefixes haven't been needed in any other browser for years and should be removed.

Comment: Check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox#Common_issues

Answer (score -1):

**Center the alignments for all the items of the flexible  element:**

The **justify-content** property aligns the flexible container's items when the items do not use all available space on the main-axis (horizontally).

Use **the align-items** property to align the items vertically.

```css
.item-center{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
height:400px;
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-center">
<div class="Hello-world"> Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the person said Div is not getting centered in parent div. so this is my answer to that question.